# Cannot find module 'firebase-functions'

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
cosnt functions = require(firebase-functions);
exports.sayHello = functions.http.onCall((data,context) =>{
return 'Hey there :D";
})
```

I have the above code, pretty basic, just wanna deploy it to Firebase Cloud Functions.
I'm running latest version Node, and have done `npm install -g firebase-tools`, `firebase init`, followed by `firebase deploy --only functions`.
However, I've been constantly getting the result

```
Cannot find module 'firebase-functions'
```

Needless to say, code cannot be deployed.
How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably told the CLI not to install the dependencies at the end.  You will have to run `npm install` from the functions folder to install the required dependencies.

If you want to work with Cloud Functions using the Firebase CLI, it will be a good idea to learn how package.json works, and how to use `npm` to work with nodejs dependencies.

Comment: I did npm install, as instructed by the CLI many times, hoping the problem solves itself.
It hasn't worked at all